# How to produce ipairs (as opposed to pairs) behavior in the C API

Tags: c, api, lua

In Lua, `pairs` and `ipairs` can iterate over the same elements in a different order:

```
> t = {[1]=1, [2]=2, [3]=3}
> for k,v in pairs(t) do print(k,v) end
2       2
1       1
3       3
> for k,v in ipairs(t) do print(k,v) end
1       1
2       2
3       3
```

When using the C API, I see only one tool for iterating over a table: the [lua_next()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_next) function which acts very much like the `pairs()` Lua function which produces the 2-1-3 order shown above.

I am looking for an efficient C method for iterating over the integer keys of a table sequentially(a C API version of ipairs).

Naively, I considered:

```
int tableLength = luaL_len(L, tableIndex);
for (i=0, i++, i>tableLength){   
    // if t[i] is not null ...
}
```

but I am unclear of potential performance issues where table sizes do not match the number of consecutive integer keys:

```
t = {[1]=1, [2]=2, [4]=4}     -- has a (reported) length of 4
t = {[1]=1, [2]=2, [40000]=4} -- has a (reported) length of 2
```

If this is indeed the way ipairs does it, then is there an easy way to start using lua_next with the last found integer key to continue to walk the rest of the table avoiding walking the integer-key portion again?  Is there a chance I will see some integer keys twice by doing so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just use rawgeti until you get a nil key:

```
// Tabs is on top of stack
for ( int i=1 ; ; i++ ) {
    lua_rawgeti(L,-1,i);
    if ( lua_isnil(L,-1) ) {
        lua_pop(L,1);
        break;
    }
    /* Do something */
    lua_pop(L,1);
}
```

By looking at the source you can see that this is what ipairs does internally: http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lbaselib.c.html#ipairsaux

Answer (score 4):

```
t = {[1]=1, [2]=2, [4]=4}     -- has a length of 4
```

Well there's your problem right there; that does not have a length of 4. You might *think* it does, and `#t` might return 4. But as far as the Lua API is concerned, the length of this table is *undefined*.

[Lua 5.1 states](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.5):

> The length of a table t is defined to be any integer index n such that t[n] is not nil and t[n+1] is nil; moreover, if t[1](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.5) is nil, n can be zero. For a regular array, with non-nil values from 1 to a given n, its length is exactly that n, the index of its last value. If the array has "holes" (that is, nil values between other non-nil values), then #t can be any of the indices that directly precedes a nil value (that is, it may consider any such nil value as the end of the array).

[Lua 5.2 is rather more explicit](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.6):

> the length of a table t is only defined if the table is a sequence, that is, the set of its positive numeric keys is equal to {1..n} for some integer n. In that case, n is its length. Note that a table like

```
 {10, 20, nil, 40}
```

> is not a sequence, because it has the key 4 but does not have the key 3. (So, there is no n such that the set {1..n} is equal to the set of positive numeric keys of that table.) Note, however, that non-numeric keys do not interfere with whether a table is a sequence.

But in both cases, the length is *undefined*.

Comment: Yes, I understand the sometimes undefined nature of table lengths, but I do not understand how this helps answer my question: "How to produce the `ipairs` behavior in the C API?"  Like I said, I _naively_ could use the reported length but I suspect there is something more sophisticated going on under the covers of ipairs.

Comment: I think Nicol Bolas's point was to say that it's best practice to completely disregard the # operator - what you call a reported length - on tables unless it meets the strict requirement of being a sequence.

In the last part of your question, you can *not* use `lua_next` to continue an ipairs-like traversal into a pairs-like traversal. `lua_next` provides no guarantee of avoiding keys already traversed in the `rawgeti` loop given by daurnimator, and may also skip over keys if you try to use it as a loop continuation this way.