# Ordered lua table looping using C API

Tags: c++, c, lua, lua-table

Consider the following lua table:

```
foo = {
    bar1 = {a = 1, b = 2, c = "hello"},
    bar2 = {a = 5, b = 2, c = "bbq"},
    bar3 = {a = 76, b = 13, c = "pwnd"}
}
```

I am trying to iterate this table using the lua C API to retrieve the key names, bar1, bar2 and bar3. I used the `lua_next(L, -2)` function to iterate as suggested by many, but the problem is that it returns the elements in random order. The order changes on each run.

I use the following code:

```
for( lua_pushnil(L); lua_next(L, -2) != 0; lua_pop(L, 1) )
{
    printf("%s\n", lua_tostring(L, -2));
}
```

Most of the time, the output is unordered, such as `bar2 bar1 bar3`. When lucky, it's ordered. Is there an easy way to loop the table keys in an ordered fashion? What would be the equivalent code as I use, but ordered? Thanks!

**Edit:**

I know I am using a map rather than an array. But in lua script we have ipairs which would work just fine for this case. I'm looking at the C API equivalent. I've found [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14172514/2065863) which gives a different answer, but it doesn't work for me, so I wonder if that answer is good or relevant.

Comment: That sounds like Lua is internally storing the keys-values as a hash-table. If you want to maintain order, perhaps a better solution would be to store the bar entries as a list, rather than a map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The order that Lua traverses tables is undefined.

If you know that the keys are of the form `barXXX`, then you can create these keys as strings dynamically in the order you wish and then get the corresponding value from the table.

Answer (score 2):

Put the names in a C array, and then order them in C.

As others are saying, the order of keys returned by the hash portion of a table is not guaranteed.

Alternatively, use an array-like structure so you can use the array part:

```
foo = {
  {name = 'bar1', a = 1,  b = 2,  c = "hello"},
  {name = 'bar2', a = 5,  b = 2,  c = "bbq"},
  {name = 'bar3', a = 76, b = 13, c = "pwnd"}
}
```

So you can use `ipairs` or the equivalent to `for i=1,#foo` to iterate over the items in order.

Answer (score 1):

Checking Lua's documentation, [the main structure that Lua supports is a Hash Table](http://www.lua.org/pil/11.html). Given that it's always going to be a hash-table, you'd probably want to reimplement `foo` [as an array](http://www.lua.org/pil/11.1.html). The `bar1`, `bar2`, etc can be part of the entry into the array like so:

```
foo = {}
foo[0] = {name='bar1', ...}
foo[1] = {name='bar2', ...}
    ...
```

or as @lhf suggested, just build the `bar` names inside a for-loop (if you know it's in sequence) and retrieve the values from `foo` table.

Comment: Just an FYI, the vizualize.me page you link to on your account has some formatting issues on the "Skills" section on Opera 26.0.  This is the best way I could think of to let you know :-).