# Lua in-place initialized table order

Tags: c++, lua

I want to be able to do the following:

```
MyObject:SetSize( { 10.0, 20.0 } )
```

But when I iterate over this on the C-side (SetSize is a C function). The order of the parameters is random.

This is the C++ side processing the table:

```
glm::vec2 State::PopVec2()
{
    glm::vec2 v();

    lua_pushnil( ls ); // first key

    int i = 0;
    while( lua_next( ls, -2 ) ) // pops key and pushes next key and value
    {
        // v[0] is x coordinate. v[1] is y coordinate.
        v[i] = (float)lua_tonumber( ls, -1 ); // get number

        lua_pop( ls, 1 );// pop value but leave next key.

        ++i;
    }

    lua_pop( ls, 1 ); // pop table

    return v;
}
```

How could I ensure consistent order without having to mess up the code on the lua side? (So basically solve this on the C++ side)

Or alternatively, what should I use as a "Vec2" equivalent on the lua side?

Comment: could you show the code on the C-side that accesses the table.

Comment: you could use [`rawgeti` to get the ipairs behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149178/how-to-produce-ipairs-as-opposed-to-pairs-behavior-in-the-c-api)

Comment: Better, simply push 1 and 2 (or 0 and 1, can't remember if Lua tables are 0-indexed) and lua_geti instead of using lua_next.

Comment: @Puppy Could you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should push 1 and 2 on to the stack (or 0,1 if tables are 0indexed) and use lua_geti instead of iterating over the table with lua_next. Another example of how your current code is incorrect is what happens if the Lua user passes `{1, 2, 3}`? You would be accessing the 3rd element of a 2-element vector.

Comment: I used `i % 2` in code, but simplified it for here.

Comment: That would still be kinda confusing, I think. And what does lua_tonumber return if it's not a number?

Comment: It would fail, but I changed it because it wasn't good, and now it handles all that just fine.